# Ubuntu Apache php and php-cli access rights

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

We have an apache server running with php7.4 on an Ubuntu system.
The apache user is the default user www-data.
My website resides in the folder:
`/var/www/html/contract-request`  and has recursively the following rights `drwxrwxr--  3 www-data www-data`so group and owner have full access.
My own user is also in the group www-data.

Now some files are in a different folder. They are mostly generated files and attachements. They reside in the following path:

```bash
$ ll /var/www/data/contract-request/
total 32
drwxrwxr-- 5 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 22 14:28 ./
drw-rwxr-- 5 www-data www-data  4096 Apr 19 08:57 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096 Nov  3  2022 application_file/
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 22 14:28 archive/
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 16384 Feb 24 12:05 attachment/
```

See? The same group and also complete access for user and group.

Now it get's weird. I had the error `string(108310) "Exception information: Message: FritIdentifierDocumentStructure: the path /var/www/data/contract-request/application_file doesn't exist.` in my php app at the following lines:

```
    if (!is_dir($this->strBasePath)) {
        throw new Exception('FritIdentifierDocumentStructure: the path ' 
              . $this->strBasePath . ' doesn't exist.');
    }
```

okay.....

So I wrote a little testscript and I placed it in the server document root:

```php
if(!is_dir('/var/www/data/contract-request/application_file')) {
        echo 'Nope. Nothing!'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
        echo 'Found it!'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

When I run the script from the client `$ php test.php` everything works. But when I call the same script from the browser, then I get 'Nope. Nothing!'

The /var/www/data/ might be an external system, which is mounted, but that should make no difference. The whole system is in the Google cloud.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro   0 1
LABEL=UEFI  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0 1
10.xx.xx.xx:/vol-d-shared-host-201/zzz-d-iadm-intra/gl-d-xxx-xxintra7/opt          /opt          nfs        rw,hard,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,vers=3,tcp   0   0
10.xx.xx.xx:/vol-d-shared-host-201/zzz-d-iadm-intra/gl-d-xxx-xxintra7/var-www/data  /var/www/data  nfs       rw,hard,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,vers=3,tcp   0   0
//nas002.zzz-mobile.de/projects          /home/System/web-prj cifs   vers=1.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,noserverino,nounix,rw,mfsymlinks,x-systemd.requires=/opt/zzz/cifs,credentials=/opt/zzz/cifs/cifs-credentials.nas002   0   0
```

Has anyone an idea what the reason might be?

Comment: Have you seen Thomas's note under is_dir page? _Note that on Linux is_dir returns FALSE if a parent directory does not have +x (executable) set for the php process._ `/var/www/data/` doesn't have `+x`

Comment: That was it! Do you want to post it as an answer? @shingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php#118314):

> Note that on Linux is_dir returns FALSE if a parent directory does not have +x (executable) set for the php process.

Since the mount point doesn't have the executable permission, `is_dir` returns false.

```
drw-rwxr-- 5 www-data www-data  4096 Apr 19 08:57 ../
   ^
```